# MPDF bug in font printing

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, mpdf

I'm using MPDF to generate a PDF from an html page, I'm having some trouble when I try the capital letter J. 
As you can see on the picture the J letter isn't on the same line as the other letter. 
Can anybody help me fixing it please? Thank you.

[image: mpdf bug image]]

Comment: This most likely is no bug, this appears to be how the capital J is designed in that font.

Comment: @mkl While simple, you should make that into an answer,

Comment: @John it was merely a (very likely) conjecture. As no one questioned it, though,  it seems to be correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no bug of MPDF, this is a feature of the font in question.

While indeed most capital letters here sit upon the base line, the fact that the J (and also the Q) go below it is not an error but a matter of font design.

It in particular improves the readability of text in this font because it makes the I and the J easier to distinguish.